# Invalid argument for Chef Directory Resource? Any Ideas why

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

So, I have the following code which is a ruby block that opens a file on disk and reads each line. Each line is a string that is a dataversion  (example: "2020_Q1_NA")

I am reading the file which has a UTF16 BOM encoding, so I open the file with that in mind, and convert each line to UTF-8. Then in the next step, I am creating a directory on D drive for each of the data versions. I am using a Dynamically Created Resource here, because the file I open is actually modified by a powershell_script resource right before the ruby_block resource.

*I also tried a non dynamically created directory resource, and that also had the same error, so that isn't the problem*

Anyways, I am getting the following error

```
Errno::EINVAL: directory[d:/Program Files/ALK/data/PCM/2020_Q1_NA
] (dynamically defined) had an error: Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - d:/Program Files/ALK/data/PCM/2020_Q1_NA
```

```
ruby_block 'get the dataversions and the paths' do
    block do
        File.open('C:\\deploy\\chefpackages\\alk_pcmworker\\cookbooks\\alk_pcmworker\\dataversions.json', 'rb:BOM|UTF-16LE') do |f|
            f.each_line do |line|
                dataversion = line.encode("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE")
                
                puts dataversion.encoding # UTF-8
                dataversionPath = File.join(node['alk']['dataversions']['datafilesroot'], dataversion)
                
                resource = Chef::Resource::Directory.new(dataversionPath, run_context)
                resource.rights(:full_control, 'Administrators', applies_to_children: true)
                resource.rights(:read_execute, 'IIS_IUSRS', applies_to_children: true)
                resource.recursive(true)
                resource.run_action(:create)
                
            end
        end
    end
    action :run
end
```

I believe it is the dataversion variable that I encoded to UTF-8 that is causing the problem since if I statically set the variable to "2020_Q1_NA", the directory resource will get created, but the encoding is causing some problem, in my findings.

Is there something I am missing and how do I get past this problem. I added the stack trace for the chef recipe as well?

**STACKTRACE**

```
Generated at 2021-01-13 09:12:37 -0500
Errno::EINVAL: ruby_block[get the dataversions and the paths] (alk_pcmworker::data_instancestore line 32) had an error: Errno::EINVAL: directory[d:/Program Files/ALK/data/PCM/2020_Q1_NA

] (dynamically defined) had an error: Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - d:/Program Files/ALK/data/PCM/2020_Q1_NA


C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `fu_mkdir'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `reverse_each'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block in mkdir_p'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `each'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `mkdir_p'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider/directory.rb:118:in `block in action_create'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `call'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider.rb:175:in `converge_by'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider/directory.rb:116:in `action_create'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider.rb:144:in `run_action'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource.rb:596:in `run_action'
C:/Users/Administrator/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/alk_pcmworker/recipes/data_instancestore.rb:49:in `block (4 levels) in from_file'
C:/Users/Administrator/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/alk_pcmworker/recipes/data_instancestore.rb:37:in `each_line'
C:/Users/Administrator/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/alk_pcmworker/recipes/data_instancestore.rb:37:in `block (3 levels) in from_file'
C:/Users/Administrator/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/alk_pcmworker/recipes/data_instancestore.rb:36:in `open'
C:/Users/Administrator/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/alk_pcmworker/recipes/data_instancestore.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in from_file'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider/ruby_block.rb:35:in `call'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider/ruby_block.rb:35:in `block in action_run'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `call'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider.rb:175:in `converge_by'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider/ruby_block.rb:34:in `action_run'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider.rb:144:in `run_action'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource.rb:596:in `run_action'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/runner.rb:74:in `run_action'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/runner.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/runner.rb:106:in `each'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/runner.rb:106:in `block in converge'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:83:in `block in execute_each_resource'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:81:in `execute_each_resource'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/runner.rb:105:in `converge'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/client.rb:658:in `block in converge'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/client.rb:653:in `catch'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/client.rb:653:in `converge'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/client.rb:692:in `converge_and_save'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/client.rb:271:in `run'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application.rb:243:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application.rb:220:in `block in run_chef_client'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application.rb:203:in `run_chef_client'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application/client.rb:413:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application/client.rb:403:in `loop'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application/client.rb:403:in `interval_run_chef_client'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application/client.rb:393:in `run_application'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application.rb:58:in `run'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client:64:in `load'
C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client:64:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I just solved this problem, by just doing the following. After the conversion, I did a inspect on the string and it had special characters, so I just removed them. This isn't the best way probably, but it solved the problem. The issue was special characters that were still there even though the string said it was UTF-8. The directory resource did create the custom folders now!!

```
dataversion = line.encode("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE")
dataversion = dataversion.inspect
                
# deleting leftover special characters
dataversion.delete! '"\\\r\\\n'
```